# How to name streams on mpv

Tags: streaming, python-3.8, mpv

I am making mpv stream videos that are stored on my server. And mpv streams them as video.mp4 Is there a way to make mpv stream with a name provided as a parameter?

for example i use:

```
import os
video = input("Enter video id :")
link = "192.168.62.1://file/path/" + video + ".mp4"
command = "mpv {link}"
print(os.popen(command).read())
```

PS: i am using windows and the serer runs on linux.

PS2: The filenames on the server are rundomly generated.